# Trying to create one home network so all my devices can talk to each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nas

I have one home router and recently started working from home so I was required to get a new (static) line from my ISP for this. My home router (Line 1 from ISP) needs to stay due to the location and the fact that it has Wi-Fi and my new business router (Line 2 from my ISP) is where my personal PC/Work PC is now connected. I have a Plex server and NAS on my home router but because of this, I cannot connect to the NAS folder/file structure due to it being on a different network (mapped drives no longer work since the move). Is there a way to connect both routers, and leave my home router in place with the Wi-Fi while retaining the static IP on my "business line" needed on my work computer required by my company (there is a RED device after the router that I use to VPN into the office). I do most of my uploading/downloading on my personal PC and then move it over to my NAS to be hosted by Plex. Ultimately I could upload/download on my Plex server and move it over to my NAS, it's just tucked away in a corner and not convenient in any way to get to it to be honest.

Personal PC: Windows 10 64-bit

Plex Server: Windows 7 64-bit

NAS: WDMYCLOUDEX4100

Home Router: NETGEAR Nighthawk X6

Business Router: Linksys AC1900

To sum it up, I have two separate lines from my ISP, one home and one business(Static) and I would like my two routers to connect to one network but maintain the static IP lines on my business router and also maintain the Wi-Fi on my home router (business router doesn't have Wi-Fi as I didn't want to pay an extra $10/month for it) if possible.

Comment: I'm confused — do you have two separate ISP connections, or did you just upgrade the one?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Does your company allow bridging home and company network? I would assume no and I would suggest to keep it separate. But if it is allowed just add an additional network card to your pc to connect to both networks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here depending on what traffic goes where. The most flexible configuration would be to nominate one router as the primary for your entire network and have it handle all routing. You could use either, but I imagine your home router is more powerful, so the config below has that do the heavy lifting. (I note there are technically superior options, but they are much harder to implement and involve changing a LAN port to a second WAN port.)

You will want to start by merging the LANs of your routers. To do this, ensure the LAN interfaces on both routers are in the same subnet but have different IP addresses – for example, have the home router on 192.168.1.1 and the work router on 192.168.1.254 and a netmask of 255.255.255.0.  Disable DHCP on the work router and ensure that the DHCP range in the home router excludes the IP of the work router. Connect an Ethernet cable from a LAN port on the home router to a LAN port on the work router.

You then want to direct traffic appropriately.   You have (at least) three options here:

If you want only your work computer to use the work connection (for all Internet), statically configure its IP address outside the DHCP allocated range, with the same netmask as the routers use, but specifying the internal IP of the business router as the gateway. In this way your computer will see all local devices on the LAN (because of the net mask) and will direct all traffic for the office computer out the office router, with all other computers getting their Internet from the home router using DHCP.

Alternatively, for all devices to be able to access the office connection for some requirements, have all devices use DHCP and default gateway of the  home router. On the home router, specify routes go to the office router (i.e., program the VPN routes into the home router with their gateway being the office router internal IP). You could even program some additional routes to crudely balance internet traffic between the two routers – e.g., with a route of 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 half the IPs on the Internet will be specified.

The third alternative would be to have everything use DHCP and add static  routes to your home computer with the gateway of the office router. In this way the office router would only be used by your home computer. You might need to create a bat file or bash script to manually add the routes.

Comment: Usually you‘re right. But what about the red device? Ich would suggest another router behind the home router and red device but the question would be if the company allows bridging these networks.

Comment: @AndreasRehm - Good point - I guess it depends what is understood by "after the router". I'd interpreted it as a second router on the Internet side of the connection - in which case it makes no difference, but if its between the PC and network it may kill other connectivity regardless.

Answer (score -1):

I would, and have, used LogMeIn Hamachi ( https://www.vpn.net ) for a situation like this.

Create an account, log in, go to Networks > My Networks and click on the Add Network button. When creating the network, feel free to change some of the settings to whatever your preference is, but create it as a gateway network. You will only need this installed on 2 computers, so don't worry about the paid options. Once the network is created, click the edit button next to it on the My Networks page, and take note of the ID, which should be a 9 digit number with 2 dashes in it. Leave this window open.

Install Hamachi on your business computer, and a computer on your home network that is either always on, or will be on when you wish to access the devices on your network. Once the program is started up, press the button that looks like a power button, and log into the account you set up earlier. Do this on both computers.

Go back to the web page, and click the Add/Remove members option on the page you left open. You should see the 2 computers that are logged into the account displayed. Check the checkboxes in front of both of the computer names, and set the work computer as Member, and the home network computer as gateway. Click the save button.

Now in the program on both computers it should show the network, and under that the name of the other computer on the network. Both should have a green dot next to it, and the computer should have an IP address next to it. You should now be able to browse on the local home network by using local IP addresses.